# Dual booting after installing Ubuntu 11.10 from image burned on CD goes directly to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

On a brand new Dell XPS 64 bit Laptop with Windows home premium pre-installed, I have installed Ubuntu 11.10. I have downloaded the image from Ubuntu.com and burned that on a CD. Using this CD I have installed it on my machine.

I have chosen the dual boot option. Everything went well and I got an option for restart. While restarting it has directly gone to Windows. I could not see the disk partition of Ubuntu on Windows.

Then I tried to boot from the CD, "One Line Iso Linex" appeared on the screen and the system froze. I tried several times, but the result is same Can some body help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you selected the install Grub to the HDD? You can see the linux partition from the windows 7. If you really want to check the partition then open the disk manager in windows 7, there it will list the linux partition as unknown partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Boot into the Ubuntu Live CD.

Now, open a Terminal.

First, we'll identify which is the Ubuntu partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Next, we'll mount it (replace sda2 with the appropriate partition number):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

And finally, we'll install Grub to the hard disk (replace sda with the appropriate hard drive identifier):

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Now, reboot, and run this command in a Terminal when you get to the Ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should detect your Windows installation and automatically add it to the Grub menu.

Comment: I am Unable enter in to UBUNTU trough CD also

Comment: Ok, then try [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/). It's amazing.