# Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu on a Dell XPS 13 laptop that had Windows 10 preinstalled on it. I installed it from a USB flash drive on a partition.
When I boot my computer I can only boot into Windows 10 and Ubuntu is nowhere to be seen.

If I boot into my USB then I can see that Ubuntu is installed, but I can't get to it from the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: This might [help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) you out with your problem.

Comment: it doesn't :( i'm not seeing UBUNTU in the boot menu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable the hibernation mode and Fast Boot in Windows.
Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the legacy version of the Windows Control Panel (not the modern version).
Select **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and uncheck Fast Boot.
After having done this - **shutdown** the computer **completely** - do NOT reboot.
Boot into the BIOS and select Ubuntu as the default operating system to boot.

Update :

In case there is no Ubuntu entry to be found in the BIOS / UEFI settings,
re-install the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in EFI mode.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXXX /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

Note:

`sdX` = disk | `sdXX` = efi partition | `sdXXX` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use GParted - it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default operating system to boot.

Comment: Thanks! I can't see Energy Settings in the control panel?

Comment: @Haim : It is there ... something with energy ... search through the old version of control panel ... maybe fast boot is already disabled after you executed the command. :)

Comment: Ok, I restarted and still the boot menu doesn't show UBUNTU

Comment: @Haim : Did you switch the default operating system to Ubuntu in BIOS / UEFI settings ? :)

Comment: where would I do that? BTW thanks for trying to help me out

Comment: @Haim : You're welcome ! You have to look into the DELL XPS 13  manual ... but if DELL did not change it, this would be the F2 key  - so start the computer and immediately press F2 to access the BIOS settings. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I ended up figuring it out.
When I was loading the USB I was loading it and installing UBUNTU from the legacy boot. I tried it again while loading from the UEFI boot and it all works!

Comment: "Open the legacy version of the Windows Control Panel" - how to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Immediately after the motherboard / computer vendor logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

From Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
```

If this doesn't work try booting to an
Ubuntu live session from the USB flash drive that you used to install Ubuntu, and repairing the GRUB bootloader with Boot Repair. From an Ubuntu live session open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Open the Boot Repair application and select *Advanced Options* -> *Main Options* tab -> check *Reinstall GRUB* and *Unhide boot menu* as shown in the below screenshot. Click the *Apply* button. Then reboot the computer with `sudo reboot`

[image]

If the OSs were installed in different modes, dual booting Windows and Ubuntu with grub can't work. If your Windows is installed in BIOS mode, it is recommended to install your Ubuntu in BIOS mode, but if it's installed in UEFI mode, then do the same with Ubuntu. To check if your Windows is installed in UEFI, press the keyboard combination Windows + r then enter the command `msinfo32` in the Run window. In the new window that opens up look for the entry after where it says *BIOS Mode*.

[image]
          <sup>**BIOS vs. UEFI**</sup>

If you have installed Ubuntu in legacy mode on the same drive with GPT partitioning, you can use Boot Repair's *Advanced options* to uninstall grub-pc and install grub-efi-amd64. That converts the Ubuntu installation from BIOS boot to UEFI boot, the same firmware as most recently manufactured laptops with Windows pre-installed have.

#### Converting Ubuntu into UEFI mode

1. Start Boot-Repair, and select *Advanced options* -> *GRUB location* tab.
2. If you do not see a *Separate /boot/efi partition* option, this means that your PC does not have any UEFI partition.
3. If you see a *Separate /boot/efi partition* option, put a checkmark in the checkbox to the left of it, then click the *Apply* button in the lower right corner.

[image]

4. Set up your BIOS so that it boots the hard drive in UEFI mode. The way to adjust this setting depends on the specific model of the computer, but generally this setting is located in the boot priority settings under the *Boot* tab of the BIOS/UEFI setup utility.

---

#### Converting Ubuntu into BIOS mode

**Note:** Use this procedure only to convert an UEFI mode Ubuntu installation to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Such a conversion may be necessary if some hardware doesn't work correctly under UEFI mode. (Graphics cards are a common source of problems.) Converting to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode while Windows boots in UEFI mode can make the boot process more awkward -- you'll need to use the computer's built-in boot manager to switch between OSs, and some computer's have such poor boot managers that this may be impossible.

- If Ubuntu is installed on a GPT disk (you can check it via the `sudo parted -l` command), use GParted partition editor to create a BIOS-Boot partition (1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag) at the start of its disk.
- Start Boot-Repair, and select *Advanced options* -> *GRUB location* tab.
- Uncheck the *Separate /boot/efi partition* option

[image: Uncheck the Separate /boot/efi partition option]

- Click the *Apply* button in the lower right corner.
- Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in Legacy mode. Generally this setting is located in the *Boot* tab → *Boot order* section of the BIOS.

---

#### Converting Windows into GPT mode

MBR2GPT.exe is a command line tool which is located in the System32 folder in Windows 10. With it you can effectively and non-destructively convert a Windows 10 OS disk from MBR (for Legacy BIOS) to GPT partition style (for UEFI) without modifying/deleting any data on the disk or making a clean installation of Windows 10.

---

Links:

- [UEFI - Community Help Wiki, Converting Ubuntu into UEFI or Legacy mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_or_Legacy_mode)
- [Convert from EFI to BIOS boot mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/360543)

Comment: what is BIOS/UEFI splash screen?

Comment: @Line The splash screen is the black screen with the motherboard / computer manufacturer's logo on it that appears when booting the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown. Then press <kbd>F12</kbd> on boot and use arrows to choose `ubuntu` (note lowercase).

Also, you should try shutting down, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to open BIOS/UEFI settings and disable Secure Boot and make `ubuntu` top priority. Then GRUB can boot Windows.

If that doesn't work check the fast boot settings in BIOS and the power settings in Windows.

1. Search for and open *Power Options* in the Windows Start menu.
2. Click *Choose what the power buttons do* on the left side of the window.
3. Click *Change settings that are currently unavailable*.
4. Under *Shutdown settings* disable *Turn on fast startup* by unchecking it.

Comment: The problem us that UBUNTU doesn't show in the list of boot options

Comment: I had the same problem, because UEFI was pulling up the Windows 10 bootloader not GRUB.

Comment: This is the only worked answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. What fixed it for me was this:
I have 2 different hard drives installed. It took me forever to figure this out but was solved it was changing the boot priority from the first to the second drive. Probably the boot manager for ubuntu was installed on the other drive so it couldn't find it and booted straight into windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and it turned out that the problem was that there wasn't a working driver for my GPU preinstalled on the OS. My solution was to enter Recovery mode. At the GRUB menu press the down arrow key until you select the 2nd entry from the top (the entry with the recovery mode in its description) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

Now you should see this Recovery Menu:

[image]

Select the **network** option from the Recovery menu and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Select the **root** option from the Recovery menu, and then use the command line to run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && reboot` to automatically install the proprietary graphics driver.

Comment: how did you take a screenshot of the recovery menu?

Comment: @HaadeeBinHafees The screenshot is of an Ubuntu guest OS that's running in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is selecting OS boot manager in the BIOS boot Options menu and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Boot Options menu in BIOS:

[image]

A popup should appear asking whether you want Windows or Ubuntu boot manager. Use <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> to move Ubuntu to the top.

After clicking enter after selecting OS boot manager:

[image]

Then exit BIOS by saving settings. It should boot into GRUB after that. Unfortunately none of these other answers worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For all cases when grub has been successfully installed in the ESP (EFI System Partition) but the installer didn't (or couldn't) change the boot order, users have to do it manually by opening UEFI settings -> *Boot* tab (the actual menu name could vary) and select Ubuntu as the first boot option in the boot sequence. That should enable the computer to boot to the GRUB menu which in turn allows selecting Ubuntu or Windows.