# Enable to recover data and linux partition after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I have a dual-boot windows 8 and Ubuntu with a NTFS data partition on my laptop.

After a forced migration to windows 10, my computer restarted on grub rescue mode and i was enable to boot on ubuntu or on windows.

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

So i have tried to reinstall grub with boot-repair on live USB but it didn't work and my computer now boot directly on windows ...

**Current partition info (bootInfo):**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       718,847       716,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             718,848   208,764,927   208,046,080   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         826,302,464 1,000,214,527   173,912,064   5 Extended
Invalid MBR Signature found.
/dev/sda5     ? 1,524,864,998 5,236,647,937 3,711,782,940  c0 CTOS
/dev/sda6     ? 5,092,567,351 8,619,976,874 3,527,409,524  c5 DRDOS secured Extended
/dev/sda4         208,764,928   826,302,463   617,537,536   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS

/dev/sda5 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda
the logical partition /dev/sda5 is not contained in the extended partition /dev/sda3
/dev/sda5 overlaps with /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda
the logical partition /dev/sda6 is not contained in the extended partition /dev/sda3
```

/dev/sda1 -> MBR (partition correctly reconized)

/dev/sda2 -> OS windows (partition correctly reconized)

/dev/sda3 -> Extended partition

-> /dev/sda5 Logical Ubuntu partition (proably /)

-> /dev/sda6 Logical Ubuntu partition (probably /home)

On gparted, i see /dev/sda3 but logical partition isnt displayed

/dev/sda4 -> NTFS data partition

On gparted, got following error when i try to mount this partition (can't mount this partition on windows too ...) :

```
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sda4 is missing
```

Full BootInfo => http://pastebin.com/raw/FCr1WWCW

**Current partiton info (fdisk):**

```
Invalid flag 0x3261 of EBR (for partition 5) will be corrected by w(rite).
label: dos
label-id: 0x8858596d
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=      716800, type=7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=      718848, size=   208046080, type=7
/dev/sda3 : start=   826302464, size=   173912064, type=5
/dev/sda4 : start=   208764928, size=   617537536, type=7
/dev/sda5 : start=  1524864998, size=  3711782940, type=c0
```

**Scan with gpart :**
=> http://pastebin.com/raw/2N4ZDTvL

What i have to do now to recover my NTFS data and linux partition ?

Thx for help (and sorry for my english).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot) and [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/)