# EASYBCD Can't boot ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, easybcd

I have win7 and ubuntu installed on the same hdd, I tried using easybcd as I didn't know any other way of getting into linux, but after adding it and restarting I just got stuck at a bash command line, don't remember exactly what it said but I can figure it out if needed. Just trying to dual boot.

I also tried uninstalling easyBCD but I still get the boot selection menu so if anyone has a fix for linux and knows how I can remove that screen(unless I end up using easybcd) it would be gratly appreciated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

You can install easybcd again and click "edit boot menu", then choose "skip the boot menu". Then you will not have that booting screen