# Dual Boot Ubuntu18.04/Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an Alfawise X5 Mini PC - Intel Atom X5-Z8350 2GB DDR3 + 32GB ROM Gig LAN Windows 10 Android 5.1 dual boot. In trying to get rid of Android OS I managed to delete both OSs. I finally was able to get the little machine going by installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, however I am not able to reinstall Windows 10, I do not know how to access the BIOS set up in Ubuntu, so that I can change the boot drive priority.
I'll appreciate all the help!!!

Comment: Usually there is some function key (or Esc or Del,..) to press at power-up to enter the BIOS/UEFI settings, not OS dependent at all. Check the POST/Splash screen for hints on which.

Comment: Hi Sal Doe - Take a look here under the 'One Time Boot Menu' section - there's also a link to some common keys to press depending on the manufacturer : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047313/cannot-access-ubuntu-18-04-in-dual-boot-because-system-boots-straight-to-window/1047469#1047469 .If it's a 'Tablet'-esque machine (Android?) you've got it might even be holding the Volume key down while powering on.