# Ubuntu installed on second Harddrive, in UEFI it does not exist

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

The Title says most of it, but I elaborate anyway.
Today I had my 4. or 5. attempt to install Ubuntu on my PC, as Dual Boot to Windows 7. The Installation was successful, and when looking at Ubuntus kind of Partition Manager (in the live version of Ubuntu, on my USB Stick) It does say that there is Ubuntu on it.

And even Windows Partition Manager says that the Partition is some Primary one.

But when booting my PC, it just immediately goes to Windows. No big deal, just go into UEFI and change the Boot Priority. But the Harddrive with Ubuntu is not there, and I can`t add it.

For Details:
Windows 7 and Ubuntu are each on seperate Drives. Several People told me that it is better to put Ubuntu on a seperate Drive, so the Boot loader of Windows doesn`t get corrupted.

So both operating System has their own Drive. And Ubuntu definetly exist on my second one. But I can`t boot to it.

I know, I dont give much Info. I don`t know which info is needed, so if you need to know anything let me know

Comment: Windows 7 usually was BIOS/MBR, but if newer computer in last 5 years, hardware will be UEFI. And the attemping to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode can cause issues. Did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows? If BIOS install of Ubuntu, did you use Something Else and choose to install grub2's boot loader to Ubuntu drive, probably sdb, not to partition like sdb1? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got fixed by using Linux boot-repair in the live version of ubuntu. If you have any problems booting your PC after installing Ubuntu (maybe even problems booting into windows) go into the live try version of Ubuntu. Use

> apt-get install boot-repair

to install a software thats almost pure magic. It fixes boot software, even from Windows. And Ubuntu worked after it as well. I told the software to do something with the flags, and it repaired Windows Boot and made Ubuntu work as second System.