# Unable to boot into Ubuntu after W10 System Image Restore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a 500GB SSD, and a 3TB HDD. When I originally dual booted, I created a 200GB partition of the HDD, and installed Ubuntu. I just did a system image restore of my windows SSD. Now, I am unable to boot into Ubuntu. I have tried:

CMD prompt `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

Entering the boot override in my UEFI/BIOS - none of the options bring up GRUB or Ubuntu

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: An image restore often replaces everything. Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred I created the boot repair tool and autofixed before I saw this, but I am now able to boot through grub. Thanks for the information. Should I post an answer or close this question?

Comment: @TraceL You could answer your own question, then mark it as accepted (solved). Don't edit your post and add (SOLVED) tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)