# How do I get GRUB menu to let me choose instead of directly booting into Windows?

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Laptop is Hp cs0009tu with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot, boots automatically into Windows at startup and ignores Ubuntu.

Already tried:

- Disable Fast startup
- Disable Secure Boot
- Run bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi on Windows CMD
- Run boot-repair with Recommended fix
- Tried changing variables like GRUB_TIMEOUT in the file, did not work.

What else should I try? I have looked at the other questions here, and none of the fixes helped me. The mentioned question has a few fixes, but they might be possibly specific for the laptop model, I have an HP one which is difficult to do and I could not run the steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

In my HP laptop, once I had a similar problem. To resolve it, I got inside BIOS mode ( by pressing `ESC` when the laptop was starting). Then I navigated around. I found an option where all the OS were listed. The Windows on top, and Linux was on the 2nd place. I put the Linux at top. I saved the settings and exited. From then, I would see the GRUB menu at boot up time.
Now if you don't see Windows in the GRUB, try this. Inside Linux, fire up your terminal and run the command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

This refreshed the GRUB menu list and brought windows in the options. 
This is how I had resolved the issue. Hope that works.

### Edit

On my laptop, it was: `ESC` during starting > `F10` > navigate to `System Configeration` > `boot options` > `UEFI Boot Order` > `OS Boot Manager`.
Use up and down keys to select Linux, and use `F5` and `F6` to put Linux on the top. Then press `F10` to `save and exit`. ( Check the images to be clear). Please note that these options may differ if you have an older or newer BIOS. But the procedure should be almost same like this. Good luck.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did u manage to put "Linux at the top"? Everytime i try to set it, windows is always back at the top of the list.

Comment: Some with HP have said it only works if you have updated UEFI. HP was not dual boot friendly and seems to have improved. But may depend on model & whether that model's UEFI has the improvements. Other work arounds are to boot a fallback or hard drive entry using /EFI/Boot/boots64.efi, not ubuntu entry. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: On my laptop, it was: `ESC` during starting > `F10` > navigate to `System Configeration` > `boot options` > `UEFI Boot Order` > `OS Boot Manager` . Then you can put Linux at the top. I'll update the original answer with details.