# After dual-boot install, PC boots STRAIGHT to Windows with no choice for Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I installed Ubuntu from a LiveUSB yesterday, but the PC still boots directly into Windows with no choice of OS. What I tried so far :

-Check BIOS for fast boot (was disabled)

-Check Windows boot (UEFI)

-Check priorities on BIOS (Windows was always on top, no Ubuntu option)

-Execute commands to update grub (says works but problem keeps happening)

Note : I have installed Ubuntu on sda7 (the / root), swap on sda8 and boot on sda9 / Also boot repair says it needs to be on EMI (error)

Thanks for your attention !

Comment: Are you trying to install a dual boot or ubuntu install only? I can't answer the question until I know more about what you are trying to do. I can't give advice on dual booting but can give some advice on overwriting windows with ubuntu as I have done it a few times on different machines. If you are trying to single boot into ubuntu the other operating system, i.e. Windows can create problems for doing that. It seems that Windows 10 was very user-unfriendly when I overwrote it for this computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! If you have used Boot-repair, please [edit] your question to include the exact error message and/or the [URL provided by Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Recommended_repair).

Comment: Im trying to dual boot not ubuntu only

Comment: FYI, Ubuntu now uses a swap file by default, instead of requiring a swap partition. Check back at AskUbuntu once you get this important issue ironed out and we can help you change _if_ you want. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq provides details.