# Dual boot issue for Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have installed Lubuntu OK. But when I restart the win7 laptop only the existing windows boot option is available. No sign of Lubuntu option. Please suggest/direct me to a fix! Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Windows 7 is usually BIOS/MBR install, but can be UEFI with gpt partitioning. In BIOS mode you have to install grub to MBR, which boots grub. If you installed grub anywhere else it will not work. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: try boot repair... see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your laptop has UEFI with secure boot enabled, you will need to go to BIOS, find a setting in there that says something like trust an EFI binary, select Ubuntu/shimx64.efi, and change your boot priority so that Ubuntu's boot manager gets loaded before Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.