# Dual boot Ubuntu Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have by mistake deleted boot logs for windows 10.
I have boot again on CDV to get it repaired.
I typed bootrec /FixMBR, bootrec /FixBoot and bootrec /rebuildBCD on windows 10 cmd line.
Unfortunately the grub2 has been bypassed and there are no option to boot ubuntu, only windows 10 starts. I want to re-install the grub2.
Would you like to advise me?

Comment: You can use Boot-Repair and its advanced options to reinstall grub. You can use Supergrub to boot install if it is otherwise ok and reinstall grub from inside your install. You need total reinstall not just the menu update that update-grub does. You can also boot with rEFInd boot manager if UEFI system. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ & http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ & http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)