# After installing Ubuntu, my PC still boots to Windows

Tags: boot, 18.04, live-usb, windows-10

So I'm trying to replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu with a USB drive. I followed the Ubuntu site's instructions very carefully and watched many videos where they finish installing Ubuntu and hit the "restart computer" button and then the next time they boot it goes directly to Ubuntu. My PC doesn't want to do that I guess. Could anyone offer me a possible solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually select the default boot partition at startup.

In windows, First download "Boot Repair Disk" (will be an iso file, but you can have YUMI or Universal-USB-Installer download and install it rather than doing so yourself). In Windows go to http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ and download Universal-USB-Installer (if you only want to work with or from 1 Linux OS with that USB drive) or http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ and download YUMI (if you want to be able to run multiple OS's from your USB Drive). Then, once their (or it) downloaded, go to the folder you downloaded it to, right click it, click Properties and click the little button which says "Unblock". Then you can run the application where you will select your USB drive from the top most drop down box (make certain your USB drive is already inserted and that the drive letter you select is the same as the letter listed in "Computer" for your USB drive), then tell it which OS you want to install to the USB drive in the next drop down box, then click the folder icon and select the location where the iso file for that OS is and select it. Then have YUMI (or universal usb installer) run. Once it's done you can reboot your computer and choose the USB drive from the boot options (if presented, but your computer may automaticly select the USB drive, or you need to change your BIOS settings to use a USB disk to boot from) and run Boot-Repair.

Or, you can install Boot Repair in Ubuntu if you open that OS rather than windows:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

There, you can open the program (and from either Ubuntu or the Boot Repair OS from your USB drive as both will look the same and provide the same functions, except the OS version only has a terminal which does not allow you to paste things which Boot Repair program has told you to use in a terminal so the Ubuntu version is easier), click the "advanced options" drop down at the bottom left of the window, ensure "Reinstall GRUB" is selected (with checkbox), then click the "Grub Location" tab and select Ubuntu as the OS to boot by default, "Place GRUB on all disks". Now click "Apply" and it will run through it's repair (which often includes a group of lines which you have to enter in a terminal and run yourself, but if it shows you more than one command then copy only one line at a time and use it in the terminal). Because you told it to "Boot "Ubuntu" by default it will now automaticlly select Ubuntu to boot when you start your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but did you install the boot routines onto your hard drive?  If it went onto the USB drive, your hard drive will still want to go where it always did.
It's a mistake I made once myself.