# installed ubuntu on xp machine and still not booting with xp or asking which operation system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I installed ubuntu 16 32bit on a windows xp machine - alongside with it..
I installed from a usb hdd, after trying it and then it decide to install. the installation asked me to define size or partition and after that it began installing finishind succssfully etc.
but after rebooting it goes to xp. 
i dont see any changesin boot ini in xp and dont see bootbak file as well. 
I was excpection a menu to ask me what is the opeating system i want the machine to load. 
shoudl i add it all to the boot ini myself?

thnx.
yos.

Comment: Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format (being the *year.month* of release) so there is no desktop release titled Ubuntu 16.  There is Ubuntu Core 16 being a specialist *snap* based release intended for IoT appliances & devices, but it doesn't have a GUI or graphical user interface and isn't a good system for a ex-XP machine (which I assume is desktop or laptop). Clarify your release please.  I wouldn't expect changes to *boot.ini* or *bootbak* files, Ubuntu uses a boot manager that is usually `grub` that doesn't use those files, you select which drive it'll go on though.

Comment: Any Ubuntu 16.xx  are EOL.And not supported on AU.

Comment: ubuntu version is : ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Xenial Xerus _release i386

Comment: what versionshould I install?  that will let me choose the operation system?  ona 32bit pc ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)