# PC not booting into ubuntu (dual boot with windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have a HP 15s-du1034TU laptop which came with windows 10 preinstalled.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04, the latest LTS version, and when I restart
the grub is not coming and the PC straightaway boots into windows.

I disabled the Fast boot and the secure boot options. Also tried the following command in the command prompt of windows 10:
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

But none of the above worked. I do not have a legacy option in the BIOS. However
I could disable secure boot as mentioned previously. In bios Boot manager always shows windows as the first option and Ubuntu is always listed as the second options, no matter whatever I do.

Is it that, the latest laptops do not allow the dual boot option? Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Those with HP have that issue. It seems to reset Windows to first. Some have updated UEFI and then only from within UEFI boot settings been able to change boot order. Others live with using UEFI boot menu. Some also use fallback or hard drive boot entry. Or use rEFInd which creates its own entry that is like the hard drive boot entry.

Comment: So, if I want to work on ubuntu in my PC, will I have to completely remove the windows OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Had the same issue with my ACER. If I recall, somewhere in the blue screen boot options menu of Windows, you have to adjust the boot priority of the `grubx64.efi` to first listing. See Boot tab.

Comment: Boot into Live Ubuntu. Then run command `sudo efibootmgr` and post output into question.

Comment: You can boot many systems from UEFI. Its just one will be first in boot order. And HP seems to automatically make Windows first all the time. Have you updated UEFI from HP, those that have with some models say then the change in boot order works but only from within UEFI, not from efibootmgr which grub uses to make Ubuntu first in boot order on install (works once).

Comment: You should still be able to boot Ubuntu from boot options. That's what I do in my Dell. I intentionally have Windows 1st as it's my primary OS.

Comment: Try to boot Ubuntu with your boot manager, run the command `sudo efibootmgr` to list boot entries. Generally, in such issue, "Windows Boot Manager" comes first in that list and its ID is "Boot0000*". So instead of keeping trying to rewrite the boot manager, try now to make Windows entry inactive with command `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -A` where XXXX is the ID numbers displayed earlier. Then you should see the "*" (star) beside "Boot0000" disappeared from that list.