# Grub menu not showing after recent Upgrade

Tags: boot, 18.04, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 in a dual-boot.
I was used to selecting what OS I can boot in the GRUB menu at startup.

Yesterday GRUB was upgraded to patch the [Boot Hole](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/grub2bootloader) security. Now the GRUB menu don't show, and the boot goes straight to Windows 10...

I already tried the following on Windows 10, but without success :

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Anyone facing the same can help?

*PS: I'm using UEFI*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Use boot-repair in live disk

Comment: It's worth checking the Boot Order in the UEFI/BIOS settings. Booting straight to Windows can occasionally be as simple as the Ubuntu boot option being below the Windows option, so it boots Windows first instead of Grub. Not sure why it would have changed with a Grub update but it's fairly easy to check, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to inspect my BIOS setup. I didn't change anything, and I even used the option "discard changes" to exit. **After exiting the setup, the GRUB menu magically showed up.**

I was able to select Ubuntu, boot it, and then run:

`sudo update-grub`

This fixed the issue; new reboots are showing the GRUB menu again.