# I need help with dual boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, windows-10, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my SSD alongside Windows 10, but I can't boot Ubuntu 20.04. It always boots Windows. I ran Boot-Repair, but it didn't work. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WvMfFgJvXN/ Here is my Boot Repair Summary.

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================


Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3

mount -r /dev/sda3 : Error code 12
Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3

mount -r /dev/sda3 : Error code 12
Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3

mount -r /dev/sda3 : Error code 12

error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda2.  Check your device.map.
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda3.  Check your device.map.
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
Failed to read last sector (1952491518): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1952491518): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda3.  Check your device.map.
Failed to read last sector (1952491518): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1952491518): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
/usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd_terminal.sh: line 177: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Advices: _______________________________________________________________________
SFS detected. You may want to retry after converting Windows dynamic partitioning (SFS partitions) to a basic disk. This can be performed via tools such as TestDisk or EASEUS-Partition-Master / MiniTool-Partition-Wizard.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway? yes

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p4,
using the following options:        nvme0n1p1/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in nvme0n1p4/fstab
Quantity of real Windows: 2
Mount nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4/boot/efi

=============== Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of nvme0n1p4 ===============

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.2

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
BootCurrent: 0009
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0009,0000,0001,0008,0006,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0006* UEFI: IP4 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(4ccc6a82b6c9,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot0007* UEFI: IP6 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(4ccc6a82b6c9,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot0008* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUGRUBX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0009* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(21,0)/HD(1,GPT,2cfd3007-5d85-481d-9b18-aa2ade562ae9,0x800,0x1ca37df)..BO

uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
BootCurrent: 0009
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0009,0000,0006,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0006* UEFI: IP4 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(4ccc6a82b6c9,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot0007* UEFI: IP6 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(4ccc6a82b6c9,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot0009* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(21,0)/HD(1,GPT,2cfd3007-5d85-481d-9b18-aa2ade562ae9,0x800,0x1ca37df)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda2.  Check your device.map.
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda3.  Check your device.map.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
Failed to read last sector (1952491518): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1952491518): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p4/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda1 starts 
                       at sector 2048. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sda1 starts at sector 63. According to the info in the 
                       boot sector, sda1 has 1023999 sectors, but according 
                       to the info from fdisk, it has 1953523056 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p4
OS#2:   Windows 10 on nvme0n1p3
OS#3:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0009
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0009,0000,0001,0008,0006,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0006* UEFI: IP4 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(4ccc6a82b6c9,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot0007* UEFI: IP6 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(4ccc6a82b6c9,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot0008* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0009* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(21,0)/HD(1,GPT,2cfd3007-5d85-481d-9b18-aa2ade562ae9,0x800,0x1ca37df)..BO

f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
1476c8ed1ce8271aab2fbe89d534cfa4   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
4f0248591a11d5432380ba65f683879b   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
1feb5f9427494e6f598603caa3af7d99   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda2    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk identifier: 613A52E2-8D70-4415-8335-5F9CB61D7D07
              Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616 732901375 732661760 349.4G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 732901376 937701375 204800000  97.7G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x788d8f45
      Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1          63 1953523119 1953523057 931.5G 42 SFS
Disk sdb: 14.33 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk identifier: A9A4A12F-51C0-4EFB-BCE5-3B5CFDA24058
      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048 30031838 30029791 14.3G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA HGST HTS721010A9:;
1:32.3kB:1000GB:1000GB:fat32::;
sdb:15.4GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0:;
1:1049kB:15.4GB:15.4GB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
nvme0n1:480GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Force MP510:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:375GB:375GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:375GB:480GB:105GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL          PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                           
├─sda1      ntfs     FAA6874CA68707F9                                                          Sistem Ayrıldı 
├─sda2      ntfs     DC9E98BD9E98919E                                                                         
└─sda3      ntfs     9C124BEE124BCC48                                                          Yeni Birim     
sdb                                                                                                           
└─sdb1      vfat     1277-BBC4                            2cfd3007-5d85-481d-9b18-aa2ade562ae9 UBUNTU 20_0    Main Data Partition
nvme0n1                                                                                                       
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     6A11-A2DA                            330dcb06-e3af-48dd-ae94-0b3b45388b47                EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               7ca0554f-884e-49af-b239-53f770bd3405                Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     7A6E18226E17D5AB                     5ee01c00-00a6-4af0-a66b-182144791c7a                Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p4 ext4     84acdf81-737d-4731-81af-818c5f1807e8 18000522-24f4-43b0-9fc2-9bc2914e6541                

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

           Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme0n1p1  60.5M  37% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
nvme0n1p3   312G  11% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
nvme0n1p4  84.2G   7% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
sda1        469M   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2       18.7G  95% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sdb1       11.7G  18% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1 rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
nvme0n1p3 rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p4 rw,relatime
sda1      rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda2      ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdb1      ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 84acdf81-737d-4731-81af-818c5f1807e8 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   84acdf81-737d-4731-81af-818c5f1807e8
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic   84acdf81-737d-4731-81af-818c5f1807e8
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-6A11-A2DA
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p4/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=84acdf81-737d-4731-81af-818c5f1807e8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=6A11-A2DA  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p4: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 349.474613190 = 375.245508608  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 353.969844818 = 380.072226816  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 353.969844818 = 380.072226816  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic                  1
 436.067604065 = 468.224024576  boot/initrd.img                                3
 436.067604065 = 468.224024576  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic               3
 436.067604065 = 468.224024576  boot/initrd.img.old                            3

=================== nvme0n1p4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17123 Jul 31 00:34 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42128 Jul 31 00:34 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Jul 31 00:34 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Jul 31 00:34 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Jul 31 00:34 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jul 31 00:34 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jul 31 00:34 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sdb
```

Comment: which Ubuntu version did you install, how did you install it, do you get grub menu while booting, or you can't boot into Ubuntu at all. Kindly provide details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: @WhiteMars Çağatay installed Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Çağatay Please write the solution as an answer, as it may help users in future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it while checking If I did something wrong on this thread (askubuntu.com/questions/221835/…) I needed to configure EFI partition for windows