# Dual boot problem with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: dual-boot

I've installed Windows 10 first, then installed Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on the same SSD drive. The first time reboot, I can choose which OS to start. But when I start Windows 10 then the next time I reboot, the system didn't display the menu to choose OS and starts directly to Windows 10.

Can anyone show me how to solve this problem?

(I'm a newbie to Ubuntu).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: You also should be able to directly boot Ubuntu (or Windows) from UEFI boot menu, often f12, but same key you used to select to boot flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

In Windows 10 run CMD as administrator paste this command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Then reboot your system and see if the boot menu is working again.

No success?

If the above method didn’t change anything, you can reverse it using the command below:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Even if the above command didn’t work, try the one below to set the boot back to Windows:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

If you're not able to boot into the Windows installation, insert the Windows installation disk and there you’ll have access to the command prompt.