# Ubuntu Not Showing Under BIOS Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows, bootloader

I'm trying to dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Here's what I did:

1. Shrunk over a 100GB using the Disk Management utility in Windows.
2. After booting Ubuntu from a USB, selected "something else" in the installation type.
3. Formatted the free space to `ext4` mounted on `/`. This is a *logical* partition created *at the beginning*.

After the installation finished, I did not see the GRUB menu and booted into Windows.

I've already done two restarts and still don't see the option on Ubuntu under the "boot" section in BIOS.

I'm booting using the default UEFI settings.

I haven't created a swap partition because my laptop has 32GB RAM and SSD storage.

Can someone please suggest how I can get around this?
(I'm using a Thinkpad T480 if that helps)

---

Update 1:

Secure boot was already disabled in BIOS (no changes made to this before or after installation)

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Logical partition? If this is an uefi system, then the disk should be GPT-partitioned and only have primary partitions.

Comment: @Slep, I'll try installing again and will select *primary* instead of *logical* this time.

Comment: Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt, but only in BIOS mode from MBR (msdos) partitioned drives. If drive is MBR, then you need to install Ubuntu in BIOS/MBR mode. But Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012 and release of Windows 8. So you should have Windows in UEFI boot mode on gpt drive.

Comment: We use a Q&A format to organize our site.  Please don't edit your solution into the question.  It won't show up as "answered" for future visitors.  We want to make sure that your contribution is helpful.  Please remove your solution from your question and add your answer below and click "Post your Answer".  Tip:  You can even come back later and accept your own answer for bonus reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

Turned-off hibernate:
Admin `cmd` > `powercfg -hibernate off`

Disabe fast startup:

- Control Panel > Power Options > (Uncheck) Turn on fast startup
- Ensured no row under "On battery" and "Pluged in" is set to Hibernate

Installation type:

- Partition: Primary
- Location : Beginning of this space
- Use as   : Ext 4 journaling file system
- Mount point: /

---

Thank you @karel , @Slep , and @oldfred