# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while running sudo apt-get upgrade on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, grub-efi

I am trying to run sudo apt-get upgrade -y but it produces the below error

```
    jamshaid@jamshaid:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up ca-certificates (20201027ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 installed ca-certificates package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu26.6) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up cryptsetup-initramfs (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cryptsetup-initramfs (--configure):
 installed cryptsetup-initramfs package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:
 snapd depends on ca-certificates; however:
  Package ca-certificates is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi:
 grub-efi depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.6); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package grub-pc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates
 grub-efi-amd64
 cryptsetup-initramfs
 snapd
 grub-efi
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jamshaid@jamshaid:~$
```

Mabe, it got corrupted when I tried to install Oracle VM and it installed python-2 and downgrade the grub to 2.x version. I didn't pay attention at that moment but having serious problems now. My mouse is not clicking outside the current window. Any solution to this?
thanks

Comment: @karel that resolved the upgrade problem but the issue is still with mouse click

Comment: it does not work outside the current window

Comment: Try uninstalling Oracle VM and the Python 2 that was installed by the Oracle VM and maybe it will solve the issue with the mouse not clicking outside the current window. VirtualBox from the default Ubuntu repositories ( `sudo apt install virtualbox` ) does not have this problem.

Comment: @karel after running the above-mentioned answer command and sudo apt-get update and upgrade, I got everything fully upgraded. I restarted the system and after that I can not start ubuntu. It has been removed from the list of OS. I have two OS installed in my laptop . Windows and Ubuntu on two different hard drives. Whenever the system starts now, it directly boots the windows and if I deselect the windows from BIOS, it says corrupt disk or OS. what should I do to get everything back without reinstalling it?

Comment: Try the answers to this question: [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/708247/)