# HP Elitebook 820 G3 - 2 SSDs can't boot to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

This is a company laptop and I added another ssd for Ubuntu. I can boot to usb installation media and successfully install ubuntu using erase disk and install ubuntu option on second SSD. I can see UEFI ubuntu on boot menu but when I select ubuntu it still boots to Windows.

I suspected bitlocker so I disabled bitlocker but still the same problem. I removed the ubuntu ssd and tried on my personal computer and it worked. Do you have any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: fastboot is already disabled and I tried powercfg /h off  but still the same

Comment: HP often needs UEFI update and only changing boot order from within its UEFI settings. Everyone else's UEFI works with efibootmgr which grub also uses to set ubuntu as first in boot order when grub is installed. Adding entry to Windows BCD may work as it is syncing BCD & UEFI. In Windows: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`