# Can't boot Ubuntu with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I followed this tutorial on how to install Linux alongside Windows 10 but it turns out that when I boot, it goes directly to Windows 10

I searched for hours for a solution but nothing! It's because of "UEFI".

Now I have both Win10 and Ubuntu but can only load Widows, how can I load Linux?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 disk with linux and another 1 with windows, go to the boot settings and set the disk with linux in priority or if you have 1 disk (linux and windows on it) the GRUB should ask you what you want to boot

Comment: Hmm, "Hello" in my answer was automatically deleted :(

Comment: I don't have discs, I installed Ubuntu on a hard drive, Win too

Comment: @barbarossaJ3 Try to reinstall GRUB. It should be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685910/how-to-install-grub-after-installing-windows-10