# I have installed dual OS to Dell laptop, now stopped booting to Ubuntu 20.04 and always booting to Windows 10. (it was working fine)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. The dual boot was working fine. Today when the laptop is started, there was some massage which I don't remember exactly, but it was similar to "**Hard disk not found**". Now the laptop is not showing the dual boot option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Windows updates or fwupdate from Ubuntu may have updated UEFI, resetting it to defaults. Double check UEFI settings.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved, by resetting UEFI and adding the ubuntu option manualy.