# I can't install Ubuntu 20.04 along side windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

i am trying to install Ubuntu along side Windows but when the instalation ends and I reset the computer it goes directly to windows, when I review the the partition in the disc it says that is not asigned and I don't know if Ubuntu where installed or not. I tried solutions that had to do with the GRUB but nothing seems to work

Comment: Read/follow one of the guides online regarding shrinking windows partition, creating an ext4 partition etc. I did it recently following guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot Also a good guide here: https://www.itechguides.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-10/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly how you partitioned your disk, but the proper way is to create a separate partition for Ubuntu formatted with ext4 file system. You will need to shrink your Windows partition first, then create a new primary partition in unallocated free space on your disk drive, format it with ext4 and set it as "/" (root file system). You can also create a separate "swap" partition or set the "swap" file on the "root" partition. When Ubuntu is installed, after reboot you should see both Ubuntu and Windows available as boot choices.

Comment: You don’t need to do any of that. The installer will do it for you. You can choose custom partitioning within the installer but it’s not necessary or advised unless you have reasons to take that path

Comment: Wrong! If you choose automatic partitioning, you will erase Windows partition and use the whole disk for Ubuntu. If you install more than one OS on the same disk, you must manually partition the disk for best results.

Comment: I don’t want to argue with you but as you go through the Ubuntu installation process you reach a stage where you have several options including “Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager” and “Erase disk and install Ubuntu”. I am talking about the first option which in my opinion is simpler for a Linux newcomer. For your information I did not mark your answer down so someone else thinks your answer could be better