# Grub missing and boots into windows

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, grub-legacy

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a PC which already had windows 10 installed. But when I bootup there isn't grub screen to elect the OS instead it boots into to windows. I have looked through several posts but most describe the reverse situation (where it boots into ubuntu instead of windows). Any ideas how to get it fixed?

Also on a few posts i saw some solutions if windows was installed in UEFI mode. But when I checked this PC it was legacy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode since 2012, so how is it legacy? If legacy be sure to make a Windows repair/recovery drive and have good backups. In BIOS mode Windows is not dual boot friendly. You only have one MBR and it must have grub to dual boot. But then Windows updates will turn fast start up back on & then grub will not boot Windows. You then have to temporarily install Windows boot loader, fix Windows & restore grub with Ubuntu live installer.