# bios booting into windows bootloader instead of ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10

Bios automatically chooses windows bootloader instead of Ubuntu. If I go to boot order menu in bios by clicking f10, only Windows bootloader is listed, not Ubuntu. However, if I go to boot options by clicking f9 Ubuntu is listed and that's how I usually boot into Ubuntu. How do I boot into Ubuntu by default? I'd rather choose which OS I want to boot into in grub(?) rather than booting into windows.
I tried installing Ubuntu 3 times with legacy boot off and safe boot on from live CD using 3 Ubuntu based OS'.

Comment: Your Ubuntu is likely installed in Legacy (BIOS) mode. If it had been installed in UEFI mode Ubuntu would be listed in the UEFI boot order.

Comment: You mention f9, is this then an HP? What model? Many with HP update UEFI and are able to change boot order in UEFI/BIOS settings f10, not boot menu f9. Both systems need to be installs in UEFI boot mode. And grub only boots Windows that is working, or not needing chkdsk nor fast start up on. And Windows may turn fast start up on, and then you have to directly boot Windows from f9 to turn fast start up back off.

Comment: Similar to what @oldfred mentioned. You might have to disable fast boot for at least one boot cycle. This is I. E. Necessary, if you change the RAM or hard disks as fast boot skips some checks and doesn't recognize some changes.

Comment: i installed it in uefi mode legacy mode had been disabled and safe boot enabled. as for the boot order comment i did mention boot order option in bios menu but forgot to say which key i used which was f10 key. ive already disabled fast boot from windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: it dint work but i found the issue, apparently in the boot order settings in bios i had to click enter on os boot manager and choose ubuntu or windows boot manager. i had to move ubuntu u using f5. ill send this as an answer later as i have to sleep rn