# How do I achieve dual boot after a custom Ubuntu install on a Windows 11 machine?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, bootloader, btrfs

I am trying to add Ubuntu to a new Windows machine. It has a 1 TB SSD with Windows 11 on it. I have shrunk the Windows partition and freed up 500 GB of space for Linux.  When I install Ubuntu there's two options "install alongside Windows" or "Something else". Since I want to use another file system (btrfs) I assume I need to choose "Something else" which is what I did. After having assigned the free space for a btrfs / partition and point to the existing EFI partition I did the install. It completed without problems. But when rebooting I was back in Windows with no Linux boot option at all. The Linux partition was shown as "unknown" in Windows.

How can I get dual boot Windows/Ubuntu in this case where I create free space for a btrfs partition to run Ubuntu on?

Comment: You did all correctly. Check UEFI boot priority.

Comment: Check the Windows power option for "fast start" is off, so shutdown is not hibernate. Does the EFI menu (some key at powerup to choose boot device/os) give you an ubuntu choice? When selected, does grub boot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)