# Unable to complete dual boot with win10 and unbuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I am attempting a dual boot with win10 and Unbuntu 20 using separate ssds. I completed the install and performed reboot, but pc booted to Windows. I cannot even get the option of using the ssd that I installed the Linux is on when I enter the boot screen. I only get Windows.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as Ubuntu products using the *year* format (ie. 20) are different to those using the *year.month* (eg. 20.04) format.

Comment: Windows 10 is usually installed as a UEFI operating system, so Ubuntu will also need to be installed that way. You must boot the USB installation media as UEFI. Do you think this might have been the problem?

Comment: No I was and I am still able to boot off the usb stick. I actually completed the install by selecting erase and install unbuntu. I then selected the empty drive I have in my laptop to install unbuntu. Install completed and I rebooted as instructed. I never saw an option to choose UEFI during the installation process. Perhaps I need to try installing a different way?  ISO is 20.04 LTS I believe.

Comment: If it's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; then please correct your question as that is **not** the product your question currently states (20 is a different system to 20.04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Thank you I will try the options listed.

Comment: You need to boot the installation media UEFI. If you aren't sure how to do this, consult your motherboard's documentation.

Comment: So we can see exactly what your configuration is, post the link to the report. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair        Often best to partition in advance with gpt & include an ESP - efi system partition. You have to boot live installer in UEFI mode like UEFI:XXXX not XXXX which then is BIOS boot. XXXX is name or label of flash drive.