# Ubuntu 20.04 did not boot after installed for dual boot with Windows 11 Pro with Secure boot is enabled

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

[This is my computer](https://youtu.be/QtUzmEH-5Lk) and I have added a new blank SATA SSD (Disc 0) for installing Ubuntu 20.04 in order to dual boot with Windows 11 Pro pre-installed on SSD (Disc 1) from the factory.

This is before installing Ubuntu.

[image]

This is after installing Ubuntu.

[image]

Unfortunately, I forgot to change **Secure Boot** to **Disabled** before installing Ubuntu by **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager**. So, the computer still boot Windows without showing **grub**. I then changed the **Secure Boot** to **Disabled**, the computer still boot Windows without showing **grub**. I have no dare to switch from **UEFI** to **Legacy**, is this the correct way ?

Comment: No, switching to Legacy is NEVER the solution. Opening UEFI settings > Boot and assuring Ubuntu (Grub) has the first boot priority is what you should do before anything else. Secure Boot has nothing to do with it and AFAIK with Windows 11 it's a requirement. There's a potential problem because now you have two EFI partitions which suggests the installation was incorrect for a dual-boot. For a dual-boot what you need to disable is Windows' Fast Startup.

Comment: Go into UEFI setup and set it to boot Ubuntu (grub) first. Grub will show you the choice to boot Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: You can have one ESP per drive without issue. Just cannot have two per drive. UEFI should let you boot ubuntu entry. If you use the UEFI boot menu (same key as you used to select USB flash drive) does it show an ubuntu entry? Some systems like HP require you to change boot order in UEFI settings, some like Acer require you to set "trust" in UEFI menu on the Ubuntu entry to authorize it as bootable, so you may need to reveiw UEFI settings. https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/p78FrA8) After I switched **Boot option #1** to **Ubuntu (PO: Apacer ...]**, the computer booted Ubuntu immediately without grub menu. And after I powered off Ubuntu and switched on , my computer did not boot any OS anymore.

Comment: When you enter the UEFI you still see both disks, right? Boot with your usb-stick (the one you used to install Ubuntu and choose 'try Ubuntu'), go to the terminal and type ```sudo update-grub```. As long as you use Grub 2.04 OS_prober (this will change with Grub 2.06 which comes with Ubuntu 22.04) is enabled and grub should see both Ubuntu and Windows.