# Unable to boot into Ubuntu after Windows - Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have installed windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 18.x Its version on my laptop at dual boot..

The installation was successful but when booted the system directly boots into windows 8.1

But when I enter boot manager and select Ubuntu to boot Black screen appears for indefinite time and doesn't boot into it...

Windows installed in C drive... Ubuntu in I drive which I had created..

Only facing issue while booting into Ubuntu no issues when booting into Windows...

Can any one suggest solution?

Comment: Hello. You question needs some info and clarity. What is the actual version of Ubuntu you installed? There is no 18.x. Ubuntu does not use windows drive letters it installs into a partition. How do you know the install was successful? Has it ever worked? What were the exact commands you used to install it?

Comment: Try pressing shift while you restart. This should open the Windows 10 boot options. You may then be able to access Ubuntu. I don't know how well it would work. See https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/best-ways-access-windows-10-boot/

This may also help. See https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-dual-boot-option-not-showing/#:~:text=1%20Enable%20the%20Boot%20Menu%20Using%20Command%20Prompt.,you%20restart%20your%20PC%20faster%20after%20shutdown.%20

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question as suggested by David.

However, in the first instance, it looks like you can try the following two options:

***Option 1: Fixing the GRUB***

- Boot into your Windows OS
- Open command prompt (Run as administrator)
- Run this command: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path EFIubuntugrubx64.efi`
- Reboot your system

*** Option 2: Disabling Fast Boot***

- Open Control Panel on your Windows OS
- Go to Power >>  Change what the power buttons do
- Click on "Change settings currently unavailable" >> Uncheck "Turn on fast start up (recommended)"
- Save your changes & reboot

Let us know if any of these solutions work out for you.

Cheers.