# Xubuntu did not show up after installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu

So I made a bootatble live usb with Xubuntu on it and installed it. I followed the guided process and partitioned my disk to install Xubuntu alongside Windows 11. Then, when I restarted, nothing happened, Windows 11 booted up as always but I just had a partition in my disk. I proceeded to delete the Xubuntu partition and extended Windows' one to bring everything back to normal. Why didn't GRUB bootloader show up and what should I do to properly install Xubuntu?

Comment: You need to understand UEFI mode and how it boots. Then it should be clear that sometimes you need to change the boot order in UEFI settings > Boot. Some firmwares don't allow the installer to change it so it has to be done manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)