# My Ubuntu doesn't start

Tags: startup

I had more than two hours waiting my pc to start with Ubuntu but doesn't work
I try to spam shift to repair GRUB as I understand in askubuntu but doesn't work
please help me
my pc is asus with 8 ram and hdd hard disk
Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzSy9.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Unfortunately, you provide zero information that anyone can use to give an answer. Did it work previously, did you change anything etc.? Please include details that can provide any clue to what is happening.

Comment: no just I installed on my pc yesterday with installing update and when I start working today it doesn't work

Comment: Use ESC to enter GRUB. Then try to boot into a previous kernel.

Comment: thank you so when I'm now in grub mode what I should do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: this is about dual boot

Comment: You asked how to enter grub. There is no information to suggest anything else.