# GNU/GRUB damaged how do I solve it?

Tags: windows

on my computer I have dual boot(Windows 11 and Ubuntu
But GNU/GRUB is not created, it automatically starts Windows, any solution so I can boot Ubuntu.

Comment: are you sure grub is not created? did you change the boot options in your BIOS to boot grub as priority?

Comment: i once had a bug that was similar to what u described. The reason was that windows permanently changed the efi boot order in the background. I had to manually fix that by editing the boot order. I think i followed these instructions here - it is years ago now. I am sorry that the page is in german, but perhaps you can use google translate or find solutions using some keywords: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung/#Ubuntu-startet-nur-einmal https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/efibootmgr/#Auflistung-aller-Eintraege-Kurzformat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)