# Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 boot menu not showing suddenly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a problem where my GRUB menu does not appear and would boot directly into Windows directly. I have tried the solutions of editing the /etc/default/grub file but it do not seem to work.

This is my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Ubuntu is not shown in the BIOS as well.

Comment: Try changing the `/etc/default/grub` to following `GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

Comment: It's still the same. Grub menu do not appear

Comment: Is your install 21.10 that used 5.13 kernel? Only current versions are supported. You need to upgrade or install current version of Ubuntu. Did Windows do an update & reset UEFI settings or turn Windows fast start up back on. Windows updates often reset things to its defaults. Update Ubuntu to current version & check both UEFI & Windows settings like you do with any new install.

Comment: Yes, my kernel is 5.13. I could not boot into windows because I have switch my setting to AHCI mode else i cant boot into Ubuntu system (error saying acpi bios error could not resolve symbol).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)