# GRUB Menu doesn't Show up

Tags: dual-boot, server, grub2, windows, menu

I'm dual booting my Windows 10 with Ubuntu Mate, after the installation, Grub Menu doesn't show up. How do I get it to show up? Pls Help

Comment: Before anything else open UEFI settings > Boot menu and make sure is the selected at OS selection or similar, as always.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: @ChanganAuto Your successful comment is similar to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1366126/).