# Dual Boot not happening after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot

I am using Asus laptop with Windows 11 pre-installed. I installed the Ubuntu 20.04 in a new a partition but dual boot does not work. I tried everything such as disabling the secure boot, disabling the fast boot etc. None of them helped.

Kindly help me with this issue

Thank you

Comment: Does it boot into Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: It boots into windows

Comment: Usually this happens when Windows is set as boot priority in the boot sequence. If you can access boot menu(F8 I guess). You might be able to change the boot order. Set Ubuntu as the first priority. After a reboot you should be welcomed with the GRUB menu.

Comment: If Windows 11 pre-installed, you may need 22.04 to have latest kernel & drivers for very new hardware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)