# Acer laptop w/Win 10 boot to Windows, no option to boot into Ubuntu in bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

Tried several 20.04 installs with different usb sticks using the [standard instructions from the Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview): download the ISO, use Ballena Etcher to flash it to the usb drive, then boot into the USB drive to install Ubuntu.

The first time I used a custom partition, and the second time I selected "install alongside Windows [Recommended]"

Both times didn't work, and afterward there is no boot option to choose between ubuntu and windows; the default Windows bootloader automatically boots to windows. Should I just try an 18.04 dual-boot install, or do a cost-sanity analysis of buying a $300 laptop with ubuntu preinstalled? Changing bios boot setting to `legacy` didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly how you installed, if it was in EFI or BIOS mode, whether you installed a bootloader etc. You would never see an "Ubuntu option in the BIOS" so this is a bit confusing.

Comment: I've edited it; if there's anything that's confusing please let me know.  I followed the standard instructions from the Ubuntu website as mentioned above.

Comment: How new is system? You may need 22.04. What brand/model system. Some like Acer need trust in UEFI settings for boot entry. Some like HP need boot order changed in UEFI settings (not UEFI menu).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)