# I can not find my ubunto boot in BIOS after installing it o other hard drive on my system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have recently installed an additional SSD hard drive on my katana GF66 laptop. I installed an ubuntu in the new hard drive in order to make a dual boot system with windows 10. However, I can not see the recently installed ubuntu in BIOS UEFI section. The new hard drive works fin, but yet the problem remains.

Comment: What are you booting to when you power laptop? Boot into Live Ubuntu, run **sudo parted -l**, post up output into your question.

Comment: I boot to windows. The point is I do not see any options in boot for new installed ubunto.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)