# Ubuntu fails to boot on Windows 11 PC

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have a Windows 11 PC and tried to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it. Everything went fine during the install, apparently. When the PC rebooted without the install media, Windows 11 brought up a light blue screen and said that it had failed to start and my PC needed to be repaired. I allowed W11 to do the repairs since I can't lose the work I have on the W11 side.

I'd like to have a dual boot PC but have to keep my Windows side. How do I do this?

Mike Lockhart

Comment: Does the EFI menu (some key at power-up to allow you to select the boot device or OS) show "ubuntu"? Select it and see if you get grub to boot Ubuntu.  Does your EFI partition still have the ubuntu boot loaders (EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi)?

Comment: If your data is important, you must have backups, especially when making major changes to systems. You also should have a Windows repair flash drive & keep the Ubuntu live installer, so you can make repairs. Windows may not always self fix. Did you install in UEFI boot mode? What brand/model system. Some like HP, only let you change boot order in UEFI settings, not UEFI boot menu or with efibootmgr which grub uses to make Ubuntu first in boot order. Is Secure Boot on? Then install can only be UEFI, but grub may not directly boot Windows, only boot Windows from UEFI boot menu.

Comment: Check in your BIOS menu for "SATA mode." Not sure what your BIOS looks like. In mine, which is UEFI but looks like the legacy menu, it's found in the Information tab. Next to "SATA mode", if there is an option OTHER than AHCI (like if it says "RAID"), then you might have to switch this. I think that before I switched to AHCI, I had a similar problem to yours. Afterward, I was able to dual-boot normally. Switching the SATA mode isn't as simple as just switching it in the BIOS menu - a procedure must also be done in Windows. It's not hard, though. I can post the steps here if this is your case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you destroyed the EFI boot partition completely when you installed Ubuntu. (Formatted completely, installed, when asked destroy the partition clicked "yes".) Officially, there is no Windows 11 now. You can check it with `fdisk -l /dev/sda` (replace sda with whatever you drive is... nvme0n01 or whatever), but it's probably not there.

Normally, you'd have an EFI partition, a Windows Recovery Partition, the ACTUAL windows partition, and then whatever you set up for Ubuntu. (Usually one filesystem with the type "Linux filesystem")

Comment: I didn't install it on the Windows 11 drive, but on a separate drive. I have 2 other dual boot systems running Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I've never had this problem before. My W10 desktop has a similar configuration with a W10 drive and a Linux drive. Grub works fine there. I haven't had to use the BIOS to choose which OS to boot since the early 90's when I had a W3.x drive and a BSD Unix drive, both of which were under 20MB.

Comment: ubfan1's comment works. I hit my F11 on bootup and get an Ubuntu bootable drive in the list. After selecting it, GRUB runs as it should but without a W11 option.