# Ubuntu not booting in legacy system

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

I have a Dell Xps 13 l321x and I was using windows 10 normally, I then decide to install Ubuntu as the main OS, I downloaded it and do the normal install of Ubuntu in MBR since my laptop is MBR only, I burn it with Rufus in MBR mode, I installed Ubuntu successfully but after I removed the system to boot into Ubuntu, it shows operation system not found. I tried every, tried manual partitioning still not working.. pls help

Comment: Specs say that is Ivy Bridge, Intel 3rd Gen. That would then be an UEFI system. Do you have latest firmware from Dell and latest firmware for SSD? Check default boot mode in UEFI/BIOS settings. Many vendors call UEFI as BIOS, but all systems since 2012 when Windows 8 released are UEFI  with gpt partitioning as Microsoft requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

check within your BIOS to see if Ubuntu is listed in the boot section.
if Ubuntu is listed mark that as first boot.

if Ubuntu is not listed reinstall Ubuntu paying careful attention to the setup up which will require /uefi  partition formatted to fat32. this is regardless of using legacy mode for the system ...