# Can't boot into GRUB/Ubuntu after reinstalling Windows on my second SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, windows

I have 2 SSDs in my system

- one with 1TB - installed Windows 10 Pro on it
- one with 240GB - installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it

I was able to select the 240GB SSD as my 1st boot priority so GRUB always came up and gave me the choice between Ubuntu and Windows Boot Manager (while also having 2 more options I currently can't remember).

Now, 2 days ago I have formatted the SSD which had the Windows OS on it (along with the partitions, that were created while installing the OS) and repartitioned it using the Windows Media Creation Tool (and that drive only, NOT the 240GB SSD).

I can get into my Windows OS without any problems, but somehow I can't access the Ubuntu 22.04 OS (or GRUB) which is on the 240GB drive, as I can't select it in my MSI B450-A Pro Max Mainboard's BIOS. The drive is being recognized without any problems in the BIOS, I just can't select it in the Boot Options.

I vaguely remember having to do something different in BIOS to get my 240GB to be bootable, tried a lot of combinations in the BIOS, but wasn't successful. I am using UEFI as my Boot Method, UEFI+Legacy also didn't work somehow.

Is there any solution, whether how I can get the OS running again? Or is there any way to look, whether the Drive had been formatted somehow? Windows Disk Management shows, that all of the 240GB is free, but somehow I think, that this has to do with Linux having a different File-System, am I right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: If suggestions in karel's link do not work, we need more info to make specific suggestions. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your help! Seems like the drive didn't get erased, at least, that's what i was 100% able to understand from it. Here is the pastebin: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sKG3XV9f6j/ What would you suggest?

Comment: Mixed BIOS/MBR on sda and UEFI/gpt on sdb. But both grub in MBR of sda for BIOS boot and mount of an ESP on sdb for UEFI boot of Ubuntu. And that ESP now does not exist. It looks like you may have had BIOS boot, converted to UEFI boot using an ESP on sdb but that got reformatted when installing Windows on sdb.  I would backup Ubuntu data, convert sda to gpt  (will totally erase drive) and install Ubuntu to sda. I would have an ESP on sda.