# Not able to boot into ubuntu after windows update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-11

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11. After a Windows update, my system boots directly into Windows and does not show a GRUB menu, so I am unable to access Ubuntu. I attempted to fix the issue runnin boot-repair with default settings from a live USB. The result is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Dw4smk9n6S/. My system still boots directly into Windows.

I tried changing the boot order (though 'Ubuntu' is not explicitly listed), disabling secure boot as well as running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` from Windows cmd. Still booting directly into Windows. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem with a recent Windows 11 update. The boot-repair's **recommended repair** worked for me. In my case I was able to boot into Ubuntu (before repair) by restarting Windows 11 while holding down the SHIFT key. This gave me an window to choose boot options. Ubuntu was one of them. YMMV.

Comment: To be clear you used to have the grub menu and now you do not have the grub menu?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I used to have the grub menu to choose between Ubuntu and Windows. Now it just boots straight into Windows.

Comment: what about accessing efi boot menu with F12 or whatever key it is on your computer? see, for example, https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/boot_menu.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: I found a different solution, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggested solutions. After re-running boor-repair, the following line in the boot-repair summary gave the final hint:

> grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.

> grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.

Following [Wiki Ubuntu Users](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur/#Standard-Desktop-System) and this [StackExchange Artricle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693101/reinstall-grub-grub-install-warning-efi-variables-are-not-supported-on-this-s), I manually performed the steps:

```
sudo mount /dev/<boot_partition> /mnt
sudo mount /dev/<efi_partition> /mnt/boot/efi

for dir in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount --bind $dir /mnt$dir; done

sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
grub-install
update-grub
```

`mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars` was the missing bit from the Wiki article.