# Will not boot into OS

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 alongside Windows 11. At boot up at GRUB, I select Ubuntu 23.04. It starts to boot with all sorts of read outs then stops with a flashing cursor. After waiting minutes it has not booted into the OS.

This is on an Asus laptop with a nirvana gpu and a radeon gpu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)