# After clean install of 23.04, Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: boot, 23.04

Yesterday I did a clean install of 23.04 on my root partition. (There's also one `home` partition, but no Windows.)

*Edit: I installed Nvidia drivers at installation.*

Everytime I start up, I see a list of entries like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAGY7.jpg

I have no clue if they point to something substantial; to me, the dependency failures regarding `sssh` come to mind, or maybe something is up with `grub`?

Anyways, after a short while, the screen turns black with a flashing cursor, and I'm stuck forever.

The symptoms strongly resemble those of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464515/will-not-boot-into-os#1464515), but the only solution suggested there deals with Windows dual boot issues.

Also possibly related is [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464622/stuck-on-reboot-after-ubuntu-23-04-install), but I can't try the solution there because on my machine there appears to be only the 6.2.0 kernel, yet no older one.

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia drivers at the install?  Did you try to boot in recovery mode, to install the Nvidia drivers?  Please add info to your original posting.

Comment: Thanks. I ticked installation of external drivers in the installer; OP edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that on my ThinkPad T430, the Nvidia 390 drivers are the culprit.

Booting into recovery mode, opening a root terminal and performing `apt remove --purge nvidia*` solved the boot issue for the time being.

The bug involving the 390 driver package is [tracked here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/2017212).

Comment: Sadly I didn't install any nvidia drivers, so the remove command didn't work. My microserver gen 8 uses a built in Matrox G200eH2 graphics controller. I tried sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga and lspci shows them installed. But this 23.04 doesn't seem to be recognising them. Perhaps I should remove them? But how dangerous!

Comment: So I tried removing the driver with sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-mga  - as per chatGPT :), but lspci shows that Ubuntu is still using 01:00.1 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200EH. I'm losing the will to live. The bug tracker describes my issue exactly, flashing cursor in top left of blank screen